# Настройка экспорта. Выбор элементов торгового каталога

Tags: битрикс

прошу совета, мне необходимо реализовать экспорт данных каталога в количестве нескольких товаров, например, 5 выбранных по определенному свойству.
Изначально я велосипед не изобретал, пробовал на основе готовых профилей Яндекс, CSV.

добавлял новое свойство товару, и в параметрах Детальных настроек выбираю Нужный инфоблок - нужное свойство - и экспорт, данный вариант все равно все подряд выводит.

В итоге решил делать свой профиль (на основе документации), в котором просто выбор инфоблока каталога, с выбором нужных элементов для выгрузки. 
Ну вот с выбором нужных элементов в этом не получается.
Может кто делал подобное, прошу направить)) в нужном направлении.

Comment: И с чем именно проблема? На каком шаге? Пример кода приведите? Если дело не в коде, а в настройках, то покажите скринами что и как делаете. В чем видите проблему, как должно быть.

Comment: Начал по аналогии https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/catalog/templates.php. Сделал указанные файлы _run, _setup. Тут по умолчанию идет выбор инфоблока, вот в данный вариант добавить, какой-нибудь выбор нужных элементов.

Comment: Читайте про `CIBlockElement::GetList`

Comment: посмотрел, мне пока не очень дается, не пойму как из выбранного блока отобрать элементы.

Comment: используя параметр `arFilter` по нужному свойству.

Comment: Смотрите примеры как с этим работать, пробуйте на своем пример если не получается приводите пример кода, тогда можно будет помочь.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, продолжу опыты))